# FFmpeg - Commands to convert videos to be played on Android devices

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, codec

I have to convert videos on the server-side to have a good video streaming just like what Instagram does. Videos must be played without any problem on Android devices (API 16+) from URL.

**Note:** Native Android `MediaPlayer` cannot play some videos.

The currently command that I'm using is: `-profile:v Main -level 3.0 -ar 44100 -ac 1 -b:a 64k -b:v 500k -s 640x640 -r 25 -ar 44100`

The question is, what is the best commands to reach my goal?

Comment: what is your question we are not able to get your problem.

Comment: @bhaveshkaila The question is, what commands I must give FFmpeg to convert videos to a great codec what Android MediaPlayer plays them without any problem?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i source_video.avi input -acodec aac -ab 128kb -vcodec mpeg4 -b 1200kb -mbd 2 -flags +4mv+trell -aic 2 -cmp 2 -subcmp 2 -s 640x640 -title X final_video.mp4
```

Hope that helps ;)

Answer (score 2):

Android officially supports only baseline profile, even if many devices will play Main or High(?) profile, so

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264  -b:v 500k -s 640x640 -r 25 -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -c:a aac -strict -2 -ar 44100 -ac 1 -b:a 64k output
```

(You can remove `-strict -2` if your ffmpeg build is from Dec 2015 or later.)

Comment: Thanks but my experience shows `MediaPlayer` plays Main profile videos without any problem. Those videos are taken from Instagram.